# Definition of $H^{s}(\mathbb{R^{+}})$ and it's norm

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

What's the definition of $H^{s}(\mathbb{R^{+}})$(classical Sobolev space on the half line) and its norm in terms of Fourier Transform? 
I'm aware of the definition of classical Sobolev Space $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})=\{f:(1+|\chi|^{2})^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}(\chi)\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})\}$ where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier Transform of $f$. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Can I use the same definition for half line?" How would you define the Fourier transform of a function that is defined only on the half line?

Comment: I have no idea about that. But I think we can use radon transform instead.

Comment: Perhaps you can define $H^{s}(\mathbb R^+)$ as the functions supported on $\mathbb R^+$ whose Fourier transform satisfies the condition above. Otherwise you can define the closure of the Laplacian in $\mathbb R$ with boundary condition $f'(0) = 0$ and replace the Fourier transform with the spectral decomposition of that operator.